# org-mode: Specify the clocktable time using the range format

Tags: emacs, clock, org-mode, range

I expect to be able to make an Emacs org-mode [clocktable](http://orgmode.org/manual/The-clock-table.html) using the same [range format](http://orgmode.org/manual/Timestamps.html#Timestamps) as normal org-mode, but it doesn't work.

How can I specify a duration like "[2012-11-10 土 13:00]--[2012-11-10 土 14:00]" in the "#+BEGIN: clocktable" line? The :tstart tag works somewhat, but the other [tags](http://orgmode.org/manual/The-clock-table.html) don't seem to work.

I have a file like this:

```
* my timed entry
  CLOCK: [2012-11-10 土 12:14]--[2012-11-10 土 13:14] =>  1:00
```

And I generate a clocktable:

OK!

```
** working table   
#+BEGIN: clocktable :tstart "[2012-11-10 土 13:00]--[2012-11-10 土 14:00]" :maxlevel 2 :scope file 
Clock summary at [2012-11-10 土 15:28]

| Headline       | Time   |
|----------------+--------|
| *Total time*   | *0:14* |
|----------------+--------|
| my timed entry | 0:14   |
#+END: clocktable
```

NG!

```
** not working table
#+BEGIN: clocktable :tstart "[2012-11-10 土 12:00]--[2012-11-10 土 13:00]" :maxlevel 2 :scope file 
Clock summary at [2012-11-10 土 15:28]

| Headline       | Time   |
|----------------+--------|
| *Total time*   | *1:00* |
|----------------+--------|
| my timed entry | 1:00   |
#+END: clocktable
```

Answer (score 0):

In your config tag `:tend` is omited, org-mode doesn't parse `range` for `:tend`.

```
* my timed entry
  CLOCK: [2012-11-10 Сб. 12:14]--[2012-11-10 Сб. 13:14] =>  1:00

** not working table
#+BEGIN: clocktable :tstart "[2012-11-10 Сб. 12:00]" :tend "[2012-11-10 Сб. 13:00]" :maxlevel 2 :scope buffer
#+CAPTION: Clock summary at [2013-01-18 Пт. 01:16]
| Headline              | Time   |      |
|-----------------------+--------+------|
| *Total time*          | *0:46* |      |
|-----------------------+--------+------|
| my timed entry        | 0:46   |      |
| \__ not working table |        | 0:00 |
#+END: clocktable
```